# Powershell can't see "git" or "node" commands while cmd can

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Using Windows 10, I can't run certain commands from PowerShell but they all work correctly using cmd.

*PowerShell*:

**node --version**:

```
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node --version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**node.exe --version**: no output.

**node.exe**: opens a new black console (node.exe application itself).

**Get-Host | Select-Object Version**:

```
Version
-------
5.1.19041.906
```

**Get-Command node**: `The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + Get-Command node + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand`

**Get-Command node.exe**: `CommandType Name Version Source ----------- ---- ------- ------ Application node.exe 14.16.1.0 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`

**$env**:Path output has nodejs & git & other paths.

*cmd*:

everything works fine with any command.

I have git and nodejs in my PATH env variable.

What's wrong with PowerShell, what a strange behavior is this and how to fix it?

Comment: _while in PoSh_ check `$env:Path -split ';' | Sort-Object` to see if the path in that session is what is needed. please remember that the path will also vary per account AND powershell host ... so make sure to test in the _exact same setup_ that your current failure shows up in.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, everything is in path... The most surprising behavior is that having or not ".exe" matters somewhy!

Comment: @VitalySenko - Edit your question to include that information

Comment: @VitalySenko - that likely means you have something in your path that is `executable` in some way AND that matches `node`. you may want to search for the unwanted item [perhaps `node.js`?] and either remove it OR rearrange your path sequence.

Comment: So when you run `node.exe`, a new window pops up? That’s not normal. How do you start Powershell? What about other programs like `notepad` or `cmd`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Good advice with rearranging my path... but it didn't help :-)

Comment: @DanielB  I start powershell as every normal user, by clicking Powershell icon in my start menu, or "Open PowerShell here" on right click in folder... Notepad is NOT working as well!

Comment: @VitalySenko - arg! i am out of ideas ... so i will go back to lurking. good luck!